# forms 11g Compatibility with weblogic server

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, weblogic12c

I have installed weblogic server 12c, now installing Forms 11g R2( 11.1.2.1.0)

the installation Location step gives the following error:
INST-07248: Specified Weblogic home location is not a valid location
INST-07248: Specified Middleware home location is not a valid location

the weblogic server is installed in D:\oracle_MW\weblogic\wls12120

I am specified the following values in installation location step:

oracle middleware home location: D:\oracle_MW
oracle home directory:                 Oracle_FRHome1
weblogic server location:              D:\oracle_MW\weblogic\wls12120
oracle instance location:              D:\oracle_MW\asinst_1
oracle instance Name:                 asinst_1

which version of weblogic server is Compatible?

Regards:

Answer (score 2):

Weblogic server versions 10.3.5 and 10.3.6 are the only ones that are compatible with this version of Forms. 12c will NOT work. You can download older versions via the following link, just scroll down and expand the section for 10.3.5 or 10.3.6: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/wls-main-097127.html

Source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/oracle-forms-111210certmatrix-1886127.xls